# XAMPP Security and Remote Access

Tags: php, sql, security, xampp

Hello I am running tests on my XAMPP server.

Let's say we have the following scenario :-

My Laptop is running the server in a small Local Network.

And I am accessing my Server with my personal PC.

Is it possible to upload files to htdocs from my Personal PC to the Server Laptop?

If we assume that all security settings are turned off. Basically I need to remotely upload files to HTDOCS so I can use them from the server!

Comment: You can always connect to another PC via Remote Desktop and manage your files.

Comment: If the computer running XAMPP server is on the same network as your personal PC you could try sharing the htdocs folder or install an FTP server also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Web servers do not, by default, run any services that write file uploads to a directory on the server.

You'll need to run some kind of suitable service such as SFTP, Windows File & Print Sharing, or a web based file uploader script.

Comment: Ok. Port 80 is opened and no restrictions are added. Is it possible to start 2nd server and upload the files from the 2nd server to the 1st(main server) ?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by that, but you seem to be confusing the software part of a server with the hardware part. If you run multiple applications that provide a service on a computer, they all have access to the same disk.

Comment: That is not what i meant. What i meant was is it possible to create a 2 Server on My personal PC and access the 1 Server (main one,on my laptop). In other words can i transfer files between them. FileZilla on port 21 or if i can use port 80 ?

Comment: An FTP server running on a computer will not be able to write to the disk of another computer unless you provide access through some other kind of service (such as Windows File & Print Sharing or NFS)

Comment: Ahm. Thanks. Well the main point of this was to check what security holes my server has and if it was possible to upload mawlare onto the server. Well lets talk about the security part. What can actually people do if my xampp is not secured and how would they do it , what can i do to protect myself !

Comment: Thats really another question and one that does not belong on this site. Try one of the other stackexchange sites, maybe SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember doesnt XAMPP come with a FileZilla server as part of the install?

So configure the fileZilla server on the laptop, create a userid and set that userid up to be able to see the htdocs folder.

Then install FileZilla client on the desktop PC. You can then use FTP ( FileZilla ) in just the same way you would if the site was running on a real hosted server.

[FileZilla Server setup instuctions](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server)